# Takes too long Using ephtmltopdf to convert html to pdf..

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm using ephtmltopdf dll to convert an html page into pdf.I'm loading a data table into the aspx page and converting it into pdf.It works fine when the size of data table is less like some 100 to 200 records.In this case it takes some 2 min or so.But takes too long wen the size is like some 3000+ records.In this case it takes some 3 hours to convert the aspx page into pdf.The result is obtained in both the cases.It is the time taken dats the problem.There is nothing in the code that can be optimised.Is dere anyhing dat can be done..
i'm using asp.Net c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IE 8 in the server solved my problem.Dont know y its so....earlier i was using ie 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try making everything you can in the HTML static sized.  Specify pixel sizes for all cells.  I'd guess the layout is what takes the longest, trying to fit the table onto pdf pages.  Or try having your code split the 3000 rows into separate tables, one for each pdf page, instead of one massive one that the library must figure out where to split.

Would you be able to run a profiler on the library? To see what methods it spends the most time in.

Comment: but the same thing runs fine locally but takes time only on the production server.And can u xplain about profiler.